# Splash issues (d-bus, QSslSocket, libpng)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dbus, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm trying to use Splash via `scrapinghub/splash` Docker image and have some alerts coming after the first request (which is to `/robots.txt` endpoint because I'm using `scrapy-splash` plugin for `scrapy` library (with Python 3.6).

```
[-] "172.17.0.1" - - [18/Jan/2018:00:05:12 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Scrapy/1.5.0 (+https://scrapy.org)"
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
process 1: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: UUID file '/etc/machine-id' should contain a hex string of length 32, not length 0, with no other text
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
```

And the saddest thing is that it doesn't render [this page](http://floodlist.com/news). Also need to mention that sometimes it renders this page, and it contains redirect in case JS is available.

How to make it work?

**UPDATE**

When using `scrapinghub/splash:3.0` these messages still, but render works.
So should I report it as bug in `scrapinghub/splash` image or these errors can be caused by my environment?

**UPDATE**

For some reason, even `3.0` doesn't render from now, as well as `master` (docker image tag). So for every image with `latest` or `master` or `3.0` tag, after asking (form on index endpoint) for render `http://floodlist.com/news` page it only shows a page with `You are being redirected...` title.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/491) so `d-bus` problem may be harmless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These warnings/errors seems to be harmless (see [#491 on Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/491) and [#122 on scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/122))

And the problem with rendering was solved by increasing `wait` value up to 1 second. More info about rendering issues [here](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly).

Answer (score 0):

> process 1: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: UUID file '/etc/machine-id' should contain a hex string of length 32, not length 0, with no other text
>   See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.

These would appear to be fairly concise instructions on how to fix the D-Bus issue.

I don’t know about the other warnings, or whether any of them are relevant.

Comment: These errors messages appear in stdout of the docker container. So issue with d-bus is inside container?

Comment: That seems likely.